# I keep getting error after successful gradle build

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have tried to integrate SDK after which all other imported package from android.support.design are highlighted in red. When I try to run my app on an emulator, I get this error: "error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist"

I have tried to rebuild the project but that did not work. I invalidated the cache and restarted, it could not solve my problem. I implemented the SDK correctly as my code will show.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0-alpha1'
}
```

and here is the import statements.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

All widgets (TextViews, Recyclerview, Buttons . . .) are not found (cannot find symbols).

Comment: Did you try removing the import statements and auto import those widgets?

Comment: At least use the stable version of the support v.28. You should also use androidx libraries today.

Comment: @Mohanakrrishna Thank you. Some of the symbols were found but their methods are not.

Comment: @Joshegwuatu If the methods are not found then the library versions of what you are using and the library version of what you are referring might be different. Please check